# Send and sign the contract interface without forwarding the contract by mail？

Tags: docusignapi

1. Call the send and sign contract interface Send the page directly without confirmation.
2. Send and sign the contract interface without forwarding the contract by mail, can I directly open the contract in h5 ?
3. Get the status signed by each side?

We are docking docusign as our modular feature. And I would like to know if it is possible to directly adjust to the docusign signing URL after the user submits the order in our system.

We only have two contract signatories, can we get the signing status of both parties through the API?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do all of this with the DocuSign eSignature REST API.

> Call the send and sign contract interface Send the page directly
> without confirmation.

This is called [Embedded Signing](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/embedding/). You can [see an article](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-in-app-embedded/) with step-by-step instructions on how to do this.

> Send and sign the contract interface without forwarding the contract
> by mail, can I directly open the contract in h5 ?

See prior answer. The only thing is Im not sure what you mean by "h5" but if you mean the HTML element, you can use embedded signing in an iframe which is what I think you want.

> Get the status signed by each side?

Yes, you can do this. You can see an [article with step-by-step](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/get-envelope-recipients/) instructions on how to do this.